# Can I use Realm as a postgres ORM?

Tags: java, postgresql, orm, realm

Is [Realm](https://realm.io/products/java/) a ORM ?

If yes, can I use it as a ORM for Postgres?

Or is it only used with SQL?

Comment: An alternative to the "Obfuscated Relational Model" (aka ORM) is QueryDSL: http://querydsl.com/

Answer (score 1):

Realm is its own native database with its own engine.

It is a NOSQL database, and not an SQL ORM.

So no, it doesn't work with PostgreSQL.  For that, you should look into JPA with Hibernate or EclipseLink.

Answer (score 0):

Realm is an Object Store with its own native storage engine which isn't based on SQL. So if anything Realm is an OM, not an ORM since we don't have to map between a relational and object oriented model.

So no, you cannot use Realm together with Postgres. That doens't mean that Realm isn't useful for saving data though :)